# Eclipse/GGTS crash with Java 7 on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Can anyone help?  I'm having a serious problem with GGTS - the variant of Eclipse for Groovy/Grails development.  Many postings have indicated that GGTS works fine with Java 7, but that's not what I'm finding:

```
GGTS bundle ggts-3.5.1.RELEASE (based on Eclipse 4.3.2)
```

… is apparently incompatible with …

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

I'm trialling an upgrade to our Groovy/Grails package from Java 6 to Java 7.  I don't want to mess up my machine configuration, so I've done it on a separate Virtual Machine under Parallels.  This means I've a completely vanilla setup, and all I've done is to install Java 7.

I found warnings that the GGTS dmg installer doesn't work with Java 7, so I've simply untarred GGTS from the tar.z version.   And run it using `open GGTS.app`.

And GGTS crashes.  It fires up correctly, displays the main windows and a few pop-ups, and then crashes.  Every single time.   I've tried recreating the VM from scratch twice, and doing the install in several different ways.  I had the same problem when I installed Java 7 after installing GGTS.  Always the same result.

I've had the same GGTS running in a VM under Java 6, so it's not the VM.  And I don't see how it could be my configuration, as a clean VM doesn't have any.

The crash report gives:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000001b
```

I've found no references to this particular problem anywhere.

What might I do to solve it?

Many thanks for any help.

- Charles

---

Extract from crash report:

```
Process:         GGTS [346]
Path:            /Users/USER/Library/ggts-bundle/*/GGTS.app/Contents/MacOS/GGTS
Identifier:      org.springsource.ggts.ide
Version:         3.5.1 (3.5.1.201405030657-RELEASE-e43)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [124]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2014-07-05 11:13:16.902 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Report Version:  10
...
Crashed Thread:  39  Java: QuantumRenderer-0

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000001b
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah - writing out the problem suggested an answer.  I didn't expect it to work but it did.

Using the other version of GGTS 3.5.1, the one based on Eclipse 3.8.2, works fine. They're both at https://spring.io/tools/ggts/all

Guess it needs a defect report for the problem: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3858?filter=-2

- Charles